# JQuery Datatable: How to disable sorting for specific <tr>

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to disable sorting for first row of my table, that row looks like

```
<tr class="no-sort">
<td colspan="4"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't add this row to the data dipslayed.

Add code to your `fnDrawCallback` to add a row in your `thead`, or at the beginning of your `tbody` :

```
var opts = {};

opts.fnDrawCallback = function(){
    var mySpecialRow = '<tr><td>First</td><td>Second</td></tr>';

    $('#mytable thead').append(mySpecialRow);
    // or
    $('#mytable tbody').prepend(mySpecialRow);
}
$('#mytable').dataTable(opts);
```

Maybe I missed some details :

```
var $tr = $('#mytable tr.no-sort');
var mySpecialRow = $tr.html();
$tr.remove();

var opts = {};
opts.fnDrawCallback = function(){
    $('#mytable thead').append(mySpecialRow);
    // or
    $('#mytable tbody').prepend(mySpecialRow);
};

// add any other option you want
opts.sPaginationType = "full_numbers";

$('#mytable').dataTable(opts);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing such a good example,but whenever i am doing this operation it is not taking other options like i need to use "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers" option which is not working

Comment: you can add any option you like to the `opts` object

Comment: This appends/prepends only the first row in $tr. Need to loop through the $tr instead. `$.each($tr, function(index, value) { $('#mytable tbody').prepend(value); }`